# I am facing $Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage; while adding sharepint2013 webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

I am getting below error while adding WebPart in webpage

> $Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;

Please tell me things to do for resolving this error.

Comment: There can be a lot of things going wrong here. Can you please provide détails about the way you developped/packaged/deployed the Web part?

Comment: There must be some corelational id. Search that in ULS log. Is there error handling added in case it a custom webpart

Comment: It shows "Could not load file or assembly PMDashboard.Logic(i.e.my another project for logic)in logs even after the project was successfully build and assembly has signed.